# Check items of a list

Tags: list

I have this list :

`let myList1 = ["short-term"]`

And I want to get this second list with my first :

`let myList2 = ["short", "term"]`

using

```
for elem in myList1
     let myList2 = []
     code ???????????/\=add(myList2, submatch(0) 
endfor
```

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: How about `call extend(myList2, split(elem, "-"))`, does that do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it's all right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my good function :

```
function! myFunction()

   let myList1 = ["short-term"]
   let myList2 = []
   for elem in myList1  
       call extend(myList2, split(elem, "-"))
   endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: please tick your question as answered